# Stop execution of program until JDialog is exited

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I am trying to open up a bunch of `JDialog`s one after another. The goal is that only after one `JDialog` is closed the next one is created. I have tried to use `setModal(true)` for the dialogs, but somehow that does not make it work.

Just for you to get an idea, the code is roughly that:

```java
for(Object o : mylist) {
    JDialog j = new JDialog();
    j.setModal(true);
}
```

The problem with that is that it opens up all the dialogs at once, so that multiple dialogs are open. How can I get what I want?

Comment: And how you show your dialogs? Please create a [mcve] so we can easier understand your problem and provide a suitable solution.

Comment: Why not just create one `JDialog` with all the input fields/questions?  It's not a good user experience to close multiple dialog windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me. The below code displays a window containing a button with the text *GO*. When you click on the button, a `JDialog` appears with the title *0* (i.e. the digit zero) and a button with the text *Close*. When you click on the *Close* button, the `JDialog` disappears and another `JDialog` appears with the title *1* (i.e. the digit one) and a *Close* button. When you click on *Close* the `JDialog` disappears and another `JDialog`, with the title *2* appears.

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GUI {
    private JFrame  frame;

    private void closeDialog(ActionEvent event) {
        ((JDialog) ((JComponent) event.getSource()).getTopLevelAncestor()).dispose();
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button = new JButton("GO");
        button.addActionListener(this::showDialogs);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void showDialogs(ActionEvent event) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            JDialog dlg = new JDialog(frame, true);
            dlg.setTitle(Integer.toString(i));
            JButton b = new JButton("Close");
            b.addActionListener(this::closeDialog);
            dlg.add(b);
            dlg.pack();
            dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
            dlg.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new GUI().createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

- Method `showDialogs` is called when the *GO* button is clicked.
- Method `showDialogs` creates a modal `JDialog`.
- Calling method `setVisible` in the following line of code:

```java
dlg.setVisible(true);
```

Method `setVisible` only returns after the modal `JDialog` has been closed.

- When the *Close* button (in the `JDialog`) is clicked, method `closeDialog` is called.
- Method `closeDialog` disposes the `JDialog`. Essentially the `JDialog` no longer exists after it has been disposed.
- Each loop iteration (in method `showDialogs`) is performed only after the `JDialog` it displays has been closed.

Comment: That works indeed, although I do not understad why. Would you be so kind to explain to me why this works and why the the 0-window and the 1-window are not both open?